# Can I install Tensorflow and Keras on Cloud?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, pytorch, google-prediction-api, cloud

I will like to install Tensorflow and Keras on my PC. I use 32 bits OS. I learnt Tensorflow is not compatible with 32 bits. I cannot upgrade my OS to 64 bits since my hardware does not support it. I have learnt one or two things about cloud computing but I only know about how I can use it for storage purposes.

My question is, can I install Tensorflow and keras on cloud and somehow use them on my PC? Or is there a way round this as I cannot afford to get another PC for now and I cannot afford to stop learning as well?

**NOTE**: I use Windows 7 32bits

**NOTE**: I read about how one could install Tensorflow from source but the writer discourages it as he says it won't be worth the headache in the long run as the software would not be able to implement many programs because of space.

**NOTE**: I have heard about Pytorch but I don't think it is supported by 32 bits. In addition, the materials I am using for learning machine learning only focus on Tensorflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to use the cloud, since your PC is not capable, and has limited resources.
You can set up a Google Colab or Kaggle account to run Jupyter notebooks online. They will support most libraries, including Tensorflow, Keras, and Pytorch. Both will also provide limited GPU resources.

1. Google Colab has a free version you can use, just need to keep an eye on your usage.
2. Kaggle is free, you don't need to enter a competition to use the service. Kaggle also has discussion boards and public notebooks to look at for ideas.

Comment: Found Google Colab to be slow. I now use Kaggle notebooks. It is really cool. Thanks a lot.